# jquery if statement only half working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I can't for the life of me figure out why this won't work

```
$("#color").click(function () {

        if ($("a").css("color", "#ffffff")) {
       $("a").css("color","#ff0000");
     } else  {
         $("a").css("color", "#ffffff");
     };

      });
```

The first time you click, it changes the color. But it won't change it back if you click again.

everything I've looked at seems to tell me my syntax is fine but it's just not working.

Comment: You're not comparing anything in your if statement

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: `if (true) doStuff()` is basically your if statement at the moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**TRY RUNNING THE CODE SNIPPET BELOW**

In jQuery, you set css value by

```
$('a').css('color', value).
```

You get css value by

```
$('a').css('color');
```

**NOTE**: jQuery return color values in RGB format instead of hex.

In your code, you are doing

```
if ($('a').css('color', '#ffffff')){
```

You are setting color instead of comparing color.

Below is the way:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  if ($('a').css('color') === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
    $('a').css('color', '#ff0000');
  else
    $('a').css('color', '#ffffff');
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>Hello</a>
```

Comment: ah, yes this worked perfectly. My first attempt was similar to this, I was trying to do the comparison but I couldn't get it to work. Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

Statement given in place of `if` condition will always return object which is treated as `true` value. So control will always go within `if` condition, hence color `#ff0000` is applied.
Second time again color got changed to `#ffffff` but at last it again changed to `#ff0000` because if condition returns `true`. Transition to these two color change is not noticeable(it's too fast). So it seems color is not getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($("a").css("color") == "#ffffff") {
       $("a").css("color","#ff0000");
 } else  {
       $("a").css("color", "#ffffff");
 };
```

Might work. I think its better to use a class for this and use hasClass and addClass and removeClass.

Comment: it won't work, considering different browsers return different kinds of values from that. classes would be the only suitable solution

Answer (score -1):

This is close...you need to compare the value of the color.

The line `$("a").css("color", "#ffffff")` in your if statement is what causes the actual color change, and not what the value/color of your a tag is.

I would try something like this:

```
$("#color").click(function () {

    var color = $("a").css("color");

   if (color === "#ffffff" ) {
     $("a").css("color","#ff0000");
   } else  {
     $("a").css("color", "#ffffff");
   };

});
```